# Include clause for index creation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

May I know how the `include` clause improves performance in a covering index?

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX includeIndex
  ON mytable(COL1)
  INCLUDE(COL2,COL3,COL3)
```

and what is the difference between

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX includeIndex ON mytable(COL1) INCLUDE(COL2,COL3,COL3)
```

and

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nonincludeIndex ON mytable(COL1,COL2,COL3,COL3)
```

Thanks

Comment: what? can you please rephrase that and format this question?

Comment: i read some where that creation of index using the following definition "CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX includeIndex ON mytable(COL1) INCLUDE(COL2,COL3,COL3)" results better optimization than that of CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nonincludeIndex ON mytable(COL1,COL2,COL3,COL3).......but i am not able to figure out how performance increases

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the functionality of nonclustered indexes by adding nonkey columns to the leaf level of the nonclustered index. By including nonkey columns, you can create nonclustered indexes that cover more queries. This is because the nonkey columns have the following benefits:

They can be data types not allowed as index key columns.

They are not considered by the Database Engine when calculating the number of index key columns or index key size.

An index with included nonkey columns can significantly improve query performance when all columns in the query are included in the index either as key or nonkey columns. Performance gains are achieved because the query optimizer can locate all the column values within the index; table or clustered index data is not accessed resulting in fewer disk I/O operations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If your query does only query fields in the index (includes included fields) then after finding which rows to return the sql processor fdoes not have to load the actual data page to get the data. That simple. It can answer the query from the index only.